# Adjective noun and use of AND

Tags: ambiguity

> “Blue shirt and pants“

Does this grammatically mean:

A blue shirt and blue pants or a blue shirt and ALL colors of pants?

And if known, why is that the answer and what is the rule here?

Comment: It's ambiguous, either could be meant.

Comment: It certainly wouldn't be **all** colours of pants. If the pants aren't blue, then the colour is unspecified.